# Nodejs how to create custom method for readline interface

Tags: node.js, readline

How to create a custom method for readline interface ?

```
myin = {}

    myin.on = function (a,b) {

    }

    myin.resume = function () {

    }



var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: myin
  });


 rl.on('line', function (data) {
     console.log(data); 
 });
```

I want to create my input method for using in readline
like when call `myin.on("data","aaaaa") ... myin.on("data","bbb\n")` readline grab the line 
..

but I can't find any source or doc ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that !

```
myin = {}

    myin.on = function (a,b) {
                      if (a == 'data') {

                       myin.ondata= b;    

                 }
    }

    myin.resume = function () {

    }
```

and then call like this :

```
 myin.ondata("bbbb");
 myin.ondata("aaaaa\n");
```

and output of rl.on('line' is like this  : bbbbaaaaa